# Another way to pass value from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Usually we pass value in android from one activity to another activity by Intent function.Is there is any another way is possible to pass the values from one activity to another activity **with out Intent function**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Create a class that extends `android.app.Application`, then in the Manifest put this class as the name of your application

```
<application android:name=".ClassNameOfTheClassYouCreated"...>
    ...activities etc here...
</application>
```

Now, that class that you created is your application. Its lifespan is all the way as long as the application is running, it holds the activities stack and you can add some custom fields to hold your values. To get the `Application` instance from an `Activity`, hit `this.getApplication()`.

Edit regarding fields values being reset (in response to the commend by @hackbod): Using static fields on singletons is the other way to hold global values, but I find the proposed one more elegant. As of the case you mention with resetting values, that can also happen in other contexts (like incoming phone call, orientation change), which raises the need to sanitize (or check for existence, call it whatever you like) values before using them. Always!

Comment: This is strongly discouraged.  Using this approach can create all sorts of bad subtle flows through your app.  For example, if you put a a value in the Application in activity A, and are using it in activity B, then the user presses home, your process is killed, and they return to your app...  they will be returning to activity B, but in a new process, so the application no longer holds the value you last set.  Also, more generally, there is no benefit in using <application> for this anyway -- you might as well just put the value in some static global, that is the same thing, and more modular.

Comment: @hackbod I'd always found it useful for caches of drawables. 1) I don't care when images get put it or when they're cleared I just want the cache available to all instances and 2) putting anything with a context in a static variable is a highway to memory leaks. But then I guess I don't use it for any state information.

Comment: @hackbod I edited the answer for you. Also, the home button doesn't kill anything. Even the back button doesn't kill anything.

Comment: She just meant that a process *can* be killed at any time, not that it *will* happen every time you press Home or Back.

Comment: To see for yourself: press home; use "adb shell ps" to find your process; then "adb shell kill <pid>" to kill it; and now return to your app.  This will simulate what happens when the system needs to kill your process for memory while it is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Information flow can be realized in various way, all you need is a way to save and retrieve your data.

You can save and then get your data which you want it to flow via static class, file storage, database, or even remote storage by using network.

Intent is the better way. Android creates it, so use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html :

> Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications. They're the only way to share data across applications; there's no common storage area that all Android packages can access.
>
> If you want to make your own data public, you have two options: You can create your own content provider (a ContentProvider subclass) or you can add the data to an existing provider — if there's one that controls the same type of data and you have permission to write to it.

Comment: Provide one example for content providers to pass value from one activity to another activity that will helpful for me